# Why does Thread.sleep() trigger the subscription to Flux.interval()?

Tags: project-reactor

If, in a `main()` method, I execute this

```
Flux.just(1,2)
    .log()
    .subscribe();
```

I get this in the console:

```
[ INFO] (main) | onSubscribe([Synchronous Fuseable] FluxArray.ArraySubscription)
[ INFO] (main) | request(unbounded)
[ INFO] (main) | onNext(1)
[ INFO] (main) | onNext(2)
[ INFO] (main) | onComplete()
```

If instead of `just()` I use the `interval()` method:

```
Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(100))
    .take(2)
    .log()
    .subscribe();
```

the elements are not logged, unless I add `Thread.sleep()` which gives me:

```
[ INFO] (main) onSubscribe(FluxTake.TakeSubscriber)
[ INFO] (main) request(unbounded)
[ INFO] (parallel-1) onNext(0)
[ INFO] (parallel-1) onNext(1)
[ INFO] (parallel-1) onComplete()
```

The question is: why do I require to pause a thread to actually trigger the subscription ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait on main thread and let the execution complete. Your main thread terminates before next element is generated. Your first element is generated after `100 ms` so you need to wait/block the main thread. Try this:

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(100))
        .take(2)
        .doOnComplete(latch::countDown)
        .log()
        .subscribe();
latch.await(); // wait for doOnComplete
```

[CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html):

> A synchronization aid that allows one or more threads to wait until a set of operations being performed in other threads completes.

Comment: Why not just using .blockLast(). This is a convoluted way of doing the same thing.

Comment: @PrashantPandey What if there is a subscriber? It doesn't make sense to blockLast.

Comment: What would happen if you used blocklast instead?

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi It then would not need to wait on a latch but that defies the purpose of a subscriber because it is one.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat isn't subscribe non-blocking? If you use blocklast, you don't need the latch

Comment: @AniketSahrawat but if you use block instead, you don't need a latch

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi It is what was required by OP.

Comment: `The question is: why do I require to pause a thread to actually trigger the subscription ?` I don't think you actually answered this question. The OP was asking why the subscribing threads needs to block. This answer just blocks with `CountDownLatch` instead of `Thread.sleep`

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi I am not going to argue on this. The answer has details as to why it is required. If you think you have a better answer, please consider adding a new one.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I'm not arguing with you, I'm trying to understand your answer - and figure out the answer to the OP's question (I this post as I had the same question)

Answer (score 1):

`Flux.interval(..)` emits items on a `parallel`, freeing up your calling thread. This is why your program exits. What you should do is:

```
Flux.interval(Duration.of(duration))
    .take(n)
    .doOnNext(this::logElement)
    .blockLast();
```

This will block the calling thread till `doOnNext()` emits the last time (which should be the second item form the upstream).

Comment: I missed that he was subscribing in the chain. This solution does not work if there is a subscribe.

Answer (score 0):

> Flux.interval(Duration) produces a Flux that is infinite and emits regular ticks from a clock.

So your first example has no concurrency, everything happens on the same thread.  The subscription and all events must complete before the method and process ends.

By using Flux.interval you have added concurrency and asynchronous behaviour into your example. Interval is a regular clock like a metronome.  You subscribe but immediately complete and the process will usually finish before any work (onNext) is done.

Comment: In the second example, if I dont pause the _main_ process, it stops immediately, but what happens to the process _parallel-1_ ? Is it still running while not logging anything in the console ?

Comment: Test it.  I would assume the JVM exits in your test.  In a server it probably completes eventually.  But it isn't great code.  Creating subscriptions without holding onto the result and managing the lifecycle can cause issues under load.